# Error running npx to create a react-native project

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, npx

I'm trying to create a new project with typescript template using npx like this

```
npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript
```

It creates the folder but it shows me this error

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing dependencies
error Error: Command failed: yarn install
warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios > xcode > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro > metro > jest-haste-map > sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro > metro > metro-minify-uglify > uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
warning react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
warning @react-native-community/eslint-config > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.12.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0". Got "15.14.0"
error Found incompatible module.
yarn install v1.22.17
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I've checked both https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install & https://v8.dev/blog/math-random but can't find the issue, I've checked over here in Stack Overflow but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case upgrading the node version solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case run this command
npx react-native init YourProjectHere --template react-native-template-typescript --npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am running ZORIN OS(UBUNTU) so after adding sudo did job for me.

```
sudo npx react-native init ProjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where my yarn version was `3.2.0`

Then I did reset it to `yarn set version 1.22.1` and it worked well my node version is `18`

Comment: Please provide more description on answers